# how to share a File object by email?

Tags: java, android, file, email, android-intent

I create a File object programmatically. I wonder how I can share it by email directly without saving it on the device.

I would like to have a method like this:

```
private void sendFileByEmail(File aFile, String emailTitle) 
{

 Intent intentShareFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailTitle);

// and then ???...

}
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

This could be and option

```
private void sendFileByEmail(File aFile, String emailTitle) 
{


Uri path = Uri.fromFile(afile); 
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
// set the type to 'email'
emailIntent .setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
String to[] = {"asd@gmail.com"};
emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
// the attachment
emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
// the mail subject
emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent , "Send email..."));

}
```